# Is Léa Seydoux the first person to be in both Mission: Impossible and a Bond film?

Tags: first-appearance, casting, james-bond, mission-impossible

I recently found out that Léa Seydoux, who played female assassin Sabine Moreau in *Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol*, will be appearing in the newest James Bond film, *Spectre*, as Madeleine Swann.

Is this the first time that an actor from either of these franchises (Mission: Impossible or James Bond) has appeared in the other?

Please note that I **am** including the 1960's and the 1980's *Mission: Impossible* TV series as part of the Mission: Impossible franchise.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No.** German actor [Andreas Wisniewski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Wisniewski) starred in both franchises (and in *Die Hard*!).

> He is best known for his portrayal of [Necros](https://supposedlyfunblog.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/necros-the-living-daylights.png) in the 1987 Bond film *The Living Daylights* and as [Max's henchman](http://balkiara.joueb.com/images/MissionImpossible.jpg) in the 1996 blockbuster *Mission: Impossible*, and as one of Hans Gruber's (Alan Rickman) henchmen, [Tony](http://www.wearysloth.com/Gallery/ActorsW/18621-5002.gif), in the 1988 blockbuster *Die Hard*.

***Update:*** Actress [Michelle Arthur](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0037807/) played minor roles in both *GoldenEye* and *Mission: Impossible 3*. And Swedish actor [Jens Hulten](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0401638/) played minor roles in both *Skyfall* and *Mission: Impossible 5*.

***Honorable mentions:*** Both [Bruce Glover](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0323098/) (Crispin Glover's father) and [Anthony Zerbe](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001875/) played villains in Bond films and guested on the original *Mission: Impossible* show.

Comment: Wow, look like he was in *Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol* too according to his Wikipedia page.

Comment: For the record, the way I worded my question was meant to make it clear that I was including the old Mission: Impossible TV show as part of the the Mission: Impossible franchise. So your "Honorable mentions" are valid answers.

Comment: It's also noteable (albeit not specifically an answer), that one of the main actors from the '88 run of the show, specifically Tony Hamilton, was once in talks of playing James Bond himself after Roger Moore, what then ended up getting to Timothy Dalton. Although, it's likely he hadn't ended up in the *M:I* show in that case.